# How to create thin line between table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, draw

How are the thin, centered lines between "Columbia Dining" and "Subject" and "Message created"?
TableViews with static cells tend to have a similar line between each cell, but the difference is that it stretches all the way to the right of the screen. I'm not looking for any code, just somebody to point me in the right direction.

Using an ultra-thin UIImageView seems sloppy, and isn't quite as elegant. I've seen these in multiple apps but I'm not sure what is used to make them.

[image]

Comment: Any old plain `UIView` with a `backgroundColor`, `alpha` and `height` will do. For `UITableView`, you can control the separator from **Interface Builder**.

Comment: I wasn't aware they had that option. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder, select your `UITableViewController`.

Table View > Show the Attributes inspector:

[image: Table View inspector]

Change **Separator** style, color, inset, etc.

This will have the side effect of showing separators at the table view level (not the cell level). Even non-existing, empty cell, will have a separator.

---

For cell-only separators, select **Separator: None** in **IB**, and add a 1/2 pixel tall `UIView` at the bottom of your prototype cells.

Any old plain `UIView` with a `backgroundColor`, `alpha` and `height` will do. User proper layout constraints to locate that separator adequately:

[image: Custom Separators]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-35001392) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-35001392).

Comment: How exactly does adding a UIView below the cells create a separator?

Comment: Clarification: not below, but at the bottom. I will add an example to my answer.